# Django - Python : Select x random items from a list per distinct value

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Im using Mongodb with Django.

I have a django model with entries. I want to select from those entries 1, or 2 or 3 or 4 or what ever amount I need per each unique entry, So lets say the model looks like this:

```
James, 011, A, B

Ben, 012, C, B

John, 014, C, B

Jamie, 0121, B, B

Sam, 015, B, B

Alex, 031, A, B
```

So I want 1 random entry per unique department for a company.

it should give me:

```
James, 011, A, B

Sam, 011, B, B

John, 011, C, B
```

Comment: Are you using an ODM, or PyMongo directly?

Comment: Can you explain your example some more? Which of these values stands for the department? is it the last two letters, like for example A, B? Why do you want 011 for each of the names returned? Please attach an example document from your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [QuerySet.distinct() function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

```
queryset.distinct('department')
```

Comment: He's using Mongodb so I'm not sure if the same ORM functions apply?

Comment: Yup thats why Im asking it :-)